# Game in Django

Tags: jquery, django

My general website is in Django.
I want to create a subpage in which the following game happens:
A word that gets loaded from the database gets shown for 100ms.
Afterwards the user has to write out the word and is told whether his answer is right or wrong.
This game shall repeat itself ten times while the user is one the page and I want to store  afterwards in my database the answers that the user got right.

Which is the best way to solve this problem?
Ajax or should I rather use flash?
What amount of effort should I expect to program something like this?

Comment: Aupajo, why did you add the subjective tag? I don't think this is very subjective at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use jQuery to build this. It shouldn't be at all hard.